# How to fetch transaction details of Zcash wallet through API

Tags: rest, zcash

I want to fetch my transaction details in Zcash using my wallet address.
Currently, I'm using this API https://api.zcha.in/v2/mainnet/accounts/t1HyNJ2PcfaGjdkRrb6ESFa1VF7CUggVHoT
But I'm unable to fetch my required transaction details. API gives me only total receive and total sent amount.
Please someone guide me who I will get my require details from Zcash using API.

I only want to fetch receive transaction details, please Help.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [gettransaction method](https://zcash-rpc.github.io/gettransaction.html).

```
curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "gettransaction", "params": ["1075db55d416d3ca199f55b6084e2115b9345e16c5cf302fc80e9d5fbf5d48d"] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8232/
```